# Migrate all python2 packages to python3 with pip

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, pip

I have been using Python2 and pip for a long time and recently installed Python3 and pip3. I want to migrate all pip packages to pip3. How to install all the package at one go?

Since my pip list shows a long list of packages installed using pip, it is very hectic to install them one by one using pip3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, save all the packages using `pip freeze > requirements.txt` then run `pip3 install -r requirements.txt`

Comment: This does the same thing, but in two steps.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to install all your python2 packages for python3, use

```
$ pip3 install --user `pip freeze`
```